# Setting aria-label/aria-labelledby within React.cloneElement()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

Basically, I'm trying to clone an element and change its aria-label within React.cloneElement. I've got a component - ButtonArrows - that creates two Button components, one with an arrow icon pointing left, and one pointing right. I'd like to be able to programmatically change the aria-label, but the hyphen throws an error.

Here's some code showing what I'm trying to do:

```
const ButtonArrows = ({leftArrow, rightArrow, ...props})
  const prevButton = (
    <Button
      aria-label="Previous",
      icon={leftArrow}
    />
  );

  const nextButton = React.cloneElement(prevButton, {
    //this is where the problem is:
    aria-label="Next",
    icon={rightArrow}
  });

  return(<div {...props}>{prevButton}{nextButton}</div>);
}
```

and obviously I can't do `aria-label="Next"` because of the hyphen.

Any suggestions? React unfortunately doesn't have anything like `htmlFor` (to stand in for `html-for`) when it comest to aria labels. Should I just put an ariaLabel prop on Button and pass it down, or is there a way to do it directly with cloneElement that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use a plain JavaScript object here:

```
const nextButton = React.cloneElement(prevButton, {
  'aria-label': 'Next',
  icon: rightArrow
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I got so caught up in thinking about how React uses htmlFor and className I was completely overthinking it.

Comment: @kbuechner Glad I could help! If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const ButtonArrows = ({leftArrow, rightArrow, ...props})
  const prevButton = (
    <Button
      ariaLabel="Previous",
      icon={leftArrow}
    />
  );

  const nextButton = React.cloneElement(prevButton, {
    //this is where the problem is:
    ariaLabelledby="Next",
    icon={rightArrow}
  });

  return(<div {...props}>{prevButton}{nextButton}</div>);
}
```

**change aria-label to ariaLabel**

Comment: If this is like other attributes with hyphens, shouldn't the 'L' be capitalized, as in ariaLabel and ariaLabelledby?